# Map<string,string> variable is not getting added in DynamoDB Local but works well in Real DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to add Map variable using Spring for DynamoDb plugin into DynamoDbLocal database .... It doesnt give any error when I write but when I read the same variable I get a null value against the map request.

This datatype is by default managed by DynamoDbMapper I believe. Do you have any idea what wrong or what needs to be done ?

Here's my domain code

```java
package com.wt.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBIgnore;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBRangeKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Notification")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Notification implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @DynamoDBIgnore
  private NotificationCompositeKey notificationCompositeKey = new NotificationCompositeKey();

  @Getter
  @Setter
  @DynamoDBAttribute // This is the Map - Giving Null when read
  private Map<String,String> jsonMessage = new HashMap<String, String>();

  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "identityId")
  public String getIdentityId() {
    return notificationCompositeKey.getIdentityId();
  }

  public void setIdentityId(String identityId) {
    notificationCompositeKey.setIdentityId(identityId);
  }

  public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    notificationCompositeKey.setTimestamp(timestamp);
  }

  @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "notificationTimestamp")
  public long getTimestamp() {
    return notificationCompositeKey.getTimestamp();
  }

}
```

Comment: Should work - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes What is the error?

Comment: And here - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/520 looks like configuration problem.

Comment: Its working fine in real dynamoDB, atleast I can write - I havent read it from there but I getting null values in my test cases where I use DynamoDbLocal

Comment: Can you try with List instead of Map? They use SQLite as a storage, and looks like there is a bug in local version...

Comment: I tried reading from Real DynamoDB as well and its working properly but I am yet not able to read it from dynamoDBLocal in my test code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx guys - The issue got resolved and the problem was that I kept a condition if the value is null then insert blank string for that key-value in the map.

Even as per the AWS Documentation - it wont allow the Map or the List Datatype to be entered if the value is null or blank.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I presume that you have tested the code connecting to real DynamoDB on some deployed environment rather than on local.

I think, the problem is **not** on local DynamoDB. The problem should be the way you create getter and setter using `lombok` API. If you remove the `lombok` getter and setter annotation and add the getter/setter manually. It should work on local Dynamodb as well. I have seen this behavior.

```java
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "jsonMessage")
public Map<String, String> getJsonMessage() {
    return jsonMessage;
}

public void setJsonMessage(Map<String, String> jsonMessage) {
    this.jsonMessage = jsonMessage;
}
```